# Getting my ArrayList & HashMap to respond to the following methods

Tags: methods, arraylist, hashmap, increment, decrement

I'm just looking for some leeway into how I would get the empty methods below to respond to my harcoded arrayList (and HashMap if needed.).
I'll understand if no one can help me out directly, just some good advice.

```
import java.io.IOException;    
import java.text.ParseException;    
import java.util.Comparator;    
import java.util.InputMismatchException;    
import java.util.List;    
import java.util.Map.Entry;    
import java.util.Scanner;    
import java.util.ArrayList;    
import java.util.HashMap;    
import java.util.LinkedList;    
import java.util.ListIterator;    
import java.util.Collections;    
import java.util.Set;   

@SuppressWarnings("unused")    
public class Inventory     
{    
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 
    ArrayList<Sellable> groceries; 
    HashMap<String, Integer> stock;

    public Inventory()
    {
        groceries = new ArrayList<Sellable>();
        stock = new HashMap <String,Integer> ();

        //HARDCODING...:
        Sellable n1 = new Produce("Corn", 3, 3.00);

        Sellable n2 = new Snack("Natural Popcorn Seeds", 2.50);

        Sellable n3 = new Produce("Potatoes", 3, 3.00);

        Sellable n4 = new Snack("Organic Potato Chips", 2.50);

        Sellable n5 = new Produce("Apples", 5, 1.75);

        Sellable n6 = new Snack("Apple Juice - 128 oz.", 3.50);

        Sellable n7 = new Produce("Oranges", 5, 1.75);

        Sellable n8 = new Snack("Orange Juice - 128 oz.", 3.50);

        //ADD TO HASHMAP

        groceries.add(n1);

        groceries.add(n2);

        groceries.add(n3);

        groceries.add(n4);

        groceries.add(n5);

        groceries.add(n6);

        groceries.add(n7);

        groceries.add(n8);


        //PUT UP FOR PRINTING

        stock.put(n1.getName(), 50);

        stock.put(n2.getName(), 100);

        stock.put(n3.getName(), 50);

        stock.put(n4.getName(), 100);

        stock.put(n5.getName(), 50);

        stock.put(n6.getName(), 100);

        stock.put(n7.getName(), 50);

        stock.put(n8.getName(), 100);
    }

    public void add(Sellable SE) 
    {

    }


    public boolean decrementStock(String name)  
    {

    }

    public boolean decrementStock(Sellable SE)  
    {

    }

    public boolean incrementStock(String SE)  
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void add(Sellable SE) 
{
    groceries.add(SE);
}


public void decrementStock(String name)  
{
    Integer val = stock.get(name);
    if(val != null) stock.put(name, val--);
}

public void decrementStock(Sellable SE)  
{
    decrementStock(SE.getName());
}

public void incrementStock(String SE)  
{
    Integer val = stock.get(name);
    if(val != null) stock.put(name, val++);
}
```

I switched the boolean methods to void because I didn't know which are the specification about how a boolean value should be chosen as return value.

Comment: Thank you for the leeway to what was killing me here. I managed to solve the problem...